# How to reference a sidewaysfigure?

Tags: rotating, sidewaysfigure

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\caption{caption}
\label{figure1}
\centering
\includegraphics[width= 1.0\textwidth]{gfx/graphic}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

A sidewaysfigure created like in the code above can't get referenced with this:

```
\ref{fig:figure1}
```

any ideas how to accomplish that?

Comment: if the label is `figure1` why do you think `fig:figure1` should work as reference?

Comment: oh, you are completly right. I thought the "fig:" was part of the ref syntax.